# Asymptotic expansion of $\zeta(s \mid a,b)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, riemann-zeta-function

I'm interested in an asymptotic expansion of the following Riemann zeta-type function
$$
\begin{align}
  \displaystyle \zeta(s \mid a,b) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}, 
  \quad \Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1, \, s>0, \tag1
\end{align} 
$$ as $s \to 0^+$.

The case $a=b$ in $(1)$ leads to the Riemann Hurwitz zeta function with the Laurent expansion near $0$:
$$
\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s+1}}
= \frac{1}{s}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \gamma_{k}(a+1)s^{k}, \quad s>0, \tag2
\end{align}
$$ where $\displaystyle \gamma_{k}(a+1)$ are the [generalized Stieltjes constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) with $\displaystyle \gamma_{0}(a+1)=-\Gamma'(a+1)/\Gamma(a+1)$.

What is an asymptotic expansion, as $s \to 0^+$, of $\displaystyle \zeta(s \mid a,b)$ when $a\neq b$?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form for the coefficients?

Comment: Such a series exists, at least.  There are coefficients $c_k(a,b)$ such that, for some $\delta > 0$, $$\zeta(s | a,b) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k(a,b) s^k$$ for  all $0 < s < \delta$.  The series here can be used to analytically continue $\zeta(s|a,b)$ to the annulus $0 < |s| < \delta$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, I have the same conjecture, I've defined some Laurent-Stieltjes type constants by $$\zeta(s \mid a,b) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\gamma_k(a,b) s^k \tag1$$ near $0$. Then we may extend $ζ(⋅∣a,b)$ to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, as is the classic Hurwitz zeta function. The point is to prove $(1)$. Maybe the Euler–Maclaurin formula could be an interesting tool to prove $(1)$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: I've noticed your fondness for various generalizations of $\zeta$ functions, based on infinite series. In your opinion, would a generalization of the same functions, but [based on infinite products](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259044) rather than infinite series, hold any merit ?

Comment: @Lucian Even if I've some difficulty to grasp your definition, I would say keep on working on your intuition.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: For instance, $~\displaystyle\prod_{n\in\mathbf M}\bigg(1-\frac1{n^4}\bigg)~$ yields $~\dfrac1{\zeta(4)}~$ for $~\mathbf M=\mathbb P,~$ and $~\dfrac1{4\pi\text{ csch }\pi}~$ for $~\mathbf M=\mathbb N_{>1}.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $s > 0$ we have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^s(n+b)} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a-b}{(n+a)^{s+1}(n+b)} =: g(s).
$$

The series on the right-hand side converges and is analytic on $\operatorname{Re} s > -1$, so the difference on the left-hand side can be analytically continued to this region.  Consequently, the analytic continuation $\zeta(s \mid a,b)$ of your sum satisfies

$$
\zeta(s \mid a,b) = \zeta(s+1,a+1) + g(s)
$$

for $\operatorname{Re} s > -1$, $s \neq 0$ and thus has a simple pole at $s=0$ with residue $1$.

For $|s| < 1$ we have

$$
g(s) = (a-b)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{[\log(n+a)]^k}{(n+a)(n+b)} \right) \frac{(-s)^k}{k!},
$$

so for $0 < |s| < 1$

$$
\zeta(s \mid a,b) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \gamma_{k}(a+1) + (a-b)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{[\log(n+a)]^k}{(n+a)(n+b)} \right) \frac{(-s)^k}{k!}.
$$

Comment: Thank you Antonio. +1 and accepted. There is a typo in your result, the factor $a-b$ should appear in your expansion. Observe that, using the notations in my previous comment, we get $$\gamma_0(a,b)=-\psi(b+1)$$ due to the classic evaluation $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a-b}{(n+a)(n+b)} =\psi(a+1)-\psi(b+1).$$ I'm looking for an 'interesting' evaluation for $\gamma_1(a,b)$.

Answer (score 4):

We may follow Euler's lead.

Euler was the first to define a constant of the form (1734)
$$
\begin{align} 
\gamma & = \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1N-\log N\right)=0.577215\ldots. \tag1
\end{align} 
$$

Later Stieltjes found  (1885) that the Laurent series expansion around $1$ of the Riemann zeta function,
$$
\zeta(1+s) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\gamma_k s^k, \quad s \neq 0,\tag2
$$  is such that the scaled coefficients of the regular part of the expansion, now called the *Stieltjes constants*,  are given by
$$
\begin{align} 
\gamma_k& = \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log^k n}{n}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right).
\end{align} \tag3
$$

In the same vein, J.B. Wilton (1927) and B. Berndt (1972) established that the  Laurent series expansion in the  neighbourhood of $1$ of the Hurwitz zeta function 
$$
\begin{align} \zeta(1+s,a) 
= \frac1s+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \gamma_{k}(a)\:s^{k}, \quad \Re a>0, \,s\neq 0, \tag4
\end{align}
$$ is such that the scaled coefficients of the regular part of the expansion, called the *generalized Stieltjes constants*, are given by
$$
\begin{align} 
\gamma_k(a)& = \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{\log^k (n+a)}{n+a}-\frac{\log^{k+1} (N+a)}{k+1}\right), \quad \Re a>0.
\end{align} \tag5
$$ 
Do we have a form resembling the original definition of Euler's constant for our coefficients?

> **Theorem.** Let $a,b$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1$. Consider the Riemann zeta type function initially defined as
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>    \zeta(s\mid a,b) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}, 
>   \quad \Re s>0. \tag6
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Then the meromorphic extension of $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot\mid a,b)$ admits the following Laurent series expansion around $0$,
>   $$
> \zeta(s \mid a,b) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\gamma_k(a,b) s^k, \quad s \neq 0,\tag7
> $$ and $$
> \begin{align} 
> \gamma_k(a,b)& = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log^k (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right).
> \end{align} \tag8
> $$

To see this, let $a,b$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1$.
We first assume $\Re s>0$. Observing that, for each $n \geq 1$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}s^k\right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}\right|\frac{|s|^k }{k!}<\infty
$$ and that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}s^k\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac1{(n+a)^s(n+b)}\right| = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{|n+a|^{\Re s}|n+b|}<\infty,$$
we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right)  s^k \\\\
&= \lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right) s^k \\\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}s^k -\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}s^k\right) \\\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}s^k -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}s^k\right) \\\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{(n+a)^s(n+b)} +\frac1{N^s}-\frac1s\right) \\\\
&=\zeta(s \mid a,b)-\frac1{s}.
\end{align}
$$  Then we extend the preceding identity by meromorphic continuation  to all $s \neq 0$.